# how can I clear *.lobs file after deleting stored data?

Tags: java, blob, hsqldb

I have a problem with supporting program which storing images in hsqldb. images can be added and deleted. but after deleting *.lobs file don't decreasing. so  after same time *.lobs file achieve considerable size. anybody know any way to clean up this file? can you give me REAL WORKING example? or maybe exists another database systems without this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest snapshot jar for version 2.3.0.

http://www.hsqldb.org/repos/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/SNAPSHOT/

When you execute CHECKPIONT, spaces in the *.lobs file become available for new lobs. If there is any empty space near the end of the file, the file is truncated.

Before a checkpoint, no space is reused. This is to allow data recovery in case there is a system crash.